# "there is no need to/for concern"

Tags: grammar

> There is no need **for** concern
>
> There is no need **to** concern

Are both correct? I think that in the first one *concern* is a noun, and in the second one concern is a verb?

If one of these sentences is wrong, could someone explain exactly why it is wrong.

Comment: "There is no need to concern yourself" would be valid, but not "There is no need to concern".  "There is no need for concern" is valid.

Comment: ... in which the first example uses the verb _concern_ and the last the mass-noun.

Answer (score 0):

Both *to* and *for* can be correct, because the word "concern" can be both a noun and a verb.

If you are using *concern* as a noun, then use the preposition *for*, and *concern* becomes the object of the preposition.

> There is no need for concern.

On the other hand, if you are using *concern* as a verb, then use the infinitive form of the verb (*to concern*), and complete it with an object. (It needs an object because for all but obsolete usages, *concern* is a [transitive verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concern).

> There is no need *to concern yourself* (with that).

(For more about the use of infinitive phrases, see this link: [Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm).)

Comment: That's kind of half an answer. It's actually a bit more complicated than that, surprisingly. The verb *like* is also transitive too. But depending on what adjective, verb or noun we're talking about, the object of the verb will or will not be determined by some other noun phrase. So the phrase "There's no need to like" will be wonky, but "There's nothing to like" will be ok. Similarly,  "There's nobody to concern" will also be ok.

Answer (score 0):

In a sentence where "concern" is used as a verb, "to" is correct. However, the question asks whether "There is no need to concern" is correct. It is not, since it is an incomplete sentence. The sentence has no subject. You have to add a subject, such as "yourself," "him," or "her" in order for the sentence to be correct.

Comment: I would have thought the missing "him" or "her" or "yourself" would be an object rather than a subject.

Comment: If there's a subject, or implied subject, acting on it.